# SQL - Object Execution Statistic showing two runs instead of one

Tags: sql-server

So I am comparing the performance of two stored procedures

When I look at the `STATISTICS TIME` Query 1 runs in about 2/3 the time as Query 2.  When I look at the execution plans when I run both queries back to back.  Query 1 takes 43% (39 + 4) of the batch and Query 2 takes 57% of the batch

But when I look at the Object Execution Statistics report in SSMS it shows Query 1 takes longer than Query 2.  Digging into the details it shows Query 1 with double the execution.

My question is why is the report doubling up the execution?

[image]

Comment: Please provide code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendra Little covered Statistics Time in this post: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/06/tsql-measure-performance-improvements/

Essentially, I would guess that your query is going parallel and it is showing you the statistics time over all cores used in your process. Here is a quote from that blog post:

> When you look at CPU time executed for a query, you’re literally
>   seeing the amount used across all CPUs involved. This means that if
>   you’re looking at a parallel query, total CPU time may well be greater
>   than the total elapsed time for the query.
>
> This isn’t a problem— and it’s actually a good thing when it comes to
>   comparing performance!